# Flask meta charset inheritance

Tags: encoding, flask

I am working with Flask in order to develop a web page.
I have done a layout.html file with a header in which I include the 
     
encoding.
When I develop a new html file, I extend the layout.html file.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


    {% block content %}

    <h2>{{ title }}.</h2>
    <h2>Introducción</h2>
    {% endblock %}
```

My problem is that the meta encoding is not being taken and i cant write in Spanish.

Any one knows what to do?

Comment: The meta encoding is used by *browsers*, not by Flask or Jinja2 and should have no bearing on your templates, inherited or otherwise. Can you give us an example of the kinds of problems you have now?

Comment: i'm having "python.exe' has exited with code -1073741510" error when I try to use words like "Introducción", which is in spanish, whereas I inherite from the layour.html document where i have the meta encoding for utf-8.

Comment: that is not normal behaviour. Is there no traceback?